# ui-view dont load the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi i have this simple hello world in angular ui router, but i dont know why my view wont load in ui-view,but i still can see the url change.

> ```
> <body ng-app="Myapp" > 
>
>           <div ui-view="Hello"></div>
>           <a ui-sref="Hello">teste</a>
>       </body>
> ```

```
var app = angular.module('Myapp', ["ui.router"]);

        app.config(function( $stateProvider) {


                       $stateProvider.state('Hello', {

                               url: '/Hello',

                               template: "<h1>Hello World</h1>"


                            });


                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You name your view, so you have to specify which view you want to update in your routes configuration

```
$stateProvider.state('Hello', {
     url: '/Hello',
     views: {
            'Hello': {
                template: "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
                controller: 'YourController'
            }
    }
});
```